# Javascript/jQuery - how to return value from nested function

Tags: javascript

```
 <script>
                $("select").change(function () {
  var str = "";
  var price = <?php echo $row[price];?>;
  $("select option:selected").each(function () {
            str += $(this).text() + " ";
  });
  $(".plan_price").text("price : " + parseInt(str)*price + " baht");
})
.change();
    </script>
```

So I got this .each and .change function here and I wanted to return the value of str from this whole functions so that I can use the str variable value in other places in my code

The problem I have is where to put the return and the name of the function when I call it somewhere else in my code like document.write(nameOfFunction) Please help

Thanks Alot !

Tony

Comment: Use "str" as global variable

Answer (score 1):

In this case I think the only solution is to use a global variable to store the value

```
var myString;
$("select").change(function() {
    var str = "";
    var price = <?php echo $row[price];?>;
    $("select option:selected").each(function() {
                str += $(this).text() + " ";
            });
    $(".plan_price").text("price : " + parseInt(str) * price + " baht");
    myString = str;
}).change();
alert(myString)
```